# How can I directly convert the difference between two time in milliseconds to a hh:mm:ss format?

Tags: java, date

I want to convert directly (without making the calculation with many lines of code) from the difference between two millisec times to the same value written in hh:mm:ss format. 
Is there any way to do it, or do I have to proceed by the calculation/using Date or Calendar class?

Comment: Take a look at [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't want to use Calendar/date objects. Not sure why, but in this case you can use something as simple as:

```
int diff = (time2-time1)/1000

int numHrs = diff/60

diff = diff%60

int numMins = diff/60

int numSecs = diff%60
```

to get the number of hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: You left out a `%` in the last line.

Comment: Is the semicolon key broken on your keyboard?

Comment: I **never** want to use the JDK Calendar/Dates either, so I can concur with OP, then again, I don't want to reinvent Joda either. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the Calendar function like that :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

But there is what you searching for with the constant MILISECOND [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MILLISECOND).
Try this. There are a lot of constants you can use with [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String hhmmss = SimpleDateFormat("hh:MM:ss").format(new Date(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [joda](http://joda-time.sf.net), which you should be anyway:

```
String timeDiff = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:MM:ss").print(new DateTime(differenceOfDatesInMillis));
```